# strcpy_s copying more than string length to target buffer (filling with 0xFE)

Tags: c++, strcpy

I have the following C++ code:

```
std::string test = "ABC";
char buffer[30];

for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    buffer[i] = 0;

strcpy_s(buffer, 30, test.c_str());
```

After running it, I expect `buffer` to be: 
`[0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, ... 0x00]` up to its end (29th position).

Running in VS2012, I´m getting the following result:
`[0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x00, 0xFE, 0xFE, 0xFE, ... 0xFE]`

Why is `strcpy_s` copying more than my string length (3 chars + \0) ? Where is that `0xFE` coming from ?

Comment: **...it may clobber the rest of the destination array with unspecified values...**  Syntax 2) http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy

Answer (score 2):

This is allowed by [`strcpy_s`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy):

> `strcpy_s` is allowed to clobber the destination array from the last character written up to `destsz` in order to improve efficiency: it may copy in multibyte blocks and then check for null bytes.

Comment: What a detail! I will try some other method... Thanks.